# Is it possible to access ResourceFunctions with MMA <12

Tags: resourcefunction

I thought I was late to the party and that ResourceFunctions had been around for some time, but I see now from @DanielLichtblau 's post [community post here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1703373) they arrived only in June 2019.

It seems MMA 12 is required to use the built in function ResourceFunction, but many functions would probably work perfectly well in MMA <12.

The question is: can one get and use ResourceFunctions without MMA 12 - if so, how?

Comment: Try running `PacletUpdate["ResourceSystemClient"]` and then restart the kernel. That's all it took to get it into my version of Mathematica 11.3. Another option is to find the v12 version of the paclet via the Wolfram Cloud, download it, and change the version spec. I did that one time when I wanted to look at some futurized feature.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I see a note at the bottom of many resource documentation pages " requires 11.3... "  I'll try it, but is there another dependency?

Comment: you might need to download the packet as I did in my answer. I think I may have done that like 8 months ago when I wanted to try this feature out.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the web page of the resource you're trying to access. In the top-right corner there is a button "Source Notebook" that allows you to download the notebook that defines the resource function. Open it, execute it, and you're probably good to go.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** once the new `"ResourceSystemClient"` is on the paclet server all of this gymnastics will be unnecessary

Run this in the cloud:

```
rsc=PacletFind["ResourceSystemClient"][[1]]["Location"];
pac=CreateArchive[rsc,"RSC.paclet"];
CopyFile[pac, CloudObject["RSC.paclet", Permissions->"Public"]]
```

Then click on the link which will download the file.

Next, locally, install that with

```
pac = PacletInstall["path/to/RSC.paclet"]
```

That should complain about version mismatches, so then run

```
SystemOpen@pac["Location"]
```

Find the `PacletInfo.m` file and change the `MathematicaVersion->"12.0+"` to `MathematicaVersion->"11.0+"`.

Next run

```
RebuildPacletData[]
```

And if all goes well `ResourceFunction` will be made available. If it's not, you'll need to restart Mathematica to get it to show up.